# Why bundleDependencies is false in package.json ? (Incorrect type)

Tags: npm, npm-install, visual-studio-code, package.json

When i install a npm package, the following line is automatically added in all package.json files in nodes_modules :
"bundleDependencies": false,

When i open a package.json file with vscode i have a warning alert in problems tab with the message : Incorrect type. Expected "array".

It seems normal because in the npm documentation i can see that bundleDependencies parameter expect array type. So "false" is wrong type. When i replace "false" by "[]" the warning alert disappears.

It's very annoying to have this alert in ALL package.json and i can't replace the value in all dependencies.

So why "npm install MODULE" auto add bundleDependencies in package.json of all dependencies ? Why it put "false" if it's expecting array ? It's possible to disable this option ?

Thanks.

- VSCode 1.40.0
- MACOS 10.14.1
- NPM 6.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps confusing `bundleDependencies` field with the [`bundledDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#bundleddependencies) field? The former is allowed to be a boolean, "is also honored."